# Removing elements from an iframe on Soundcloud

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, iframe, soundcloud

Im trying to remove the Cookie Policy from the Soundcloud player embed.
In Firebug this is no problem, i just add "display:none" to the .cookiePolicy and its gone.
When i add this to my wordpress css however, nothing happens.

Here is what i found from another post :

http://jsbin.com/nexup/1/edit?html,css,js,output
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13497458/3289473

Can you tell me what im doing wrong and if there is another approach to this?

Comment: I ended up using this custom player: https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove it, but you can cover it up.

Place the iframe within a div container & then use absolute positioning to place an image over the "cookie policy" text.

```
<div style="position:relative;width:100%;height:200px;">
  <img src="tiny-image.jpg" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:180px;" />
  <iframe width="100% height="200"></iframe>
</div>
```